# XSLT Working Fine in Online Editor But Not in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using XSLT mediator in WSO2 ESB to transform my Legacy Service Response to CDM Service Response. But it is not Working, I have tried it in an independent online editor http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php it works fine. But in WSO2 my XSLT is not working.

**Legacy Response:**

```
<GetPersonResponse xmlns="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001">
   <Person xsi:type="ns1:Person" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ns2:PersonId xmlns:ns2="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">4224</ns2:PersonId>
      <ns3:FirstName xmlns:ns3="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">John</ns3:FirstName>
      <ns4:LastName xmlns:ns4="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Doe</ns4:LastName>
      <ns5:FatherName xmlns:ns5="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Khalid</ns5:FatherName>
      <ns6:Religion xmlns:ns6="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Islam</ns6:Religion>
      <ns7:MotherTongue xmlns:ns7="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Urrdu</ns7:MotherTongue>
      <ns8:DateOfBirth xmlns:ns8="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">1893-02-02</ns8:DateOfBirth>
      <ns9:Gender xmlns:ns9="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:GenderType">Male</ns9:Gender>
      <ns10:CurrentAddress xmlns:ns10="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:AddressDetail">
         <ns10:AddressDetailId>194</ns10:AddressDetailId>
         <ns10:StreetNo>5</ns10:StreetNo>
         <ns10:HouseNo>123</ns10:HouseNo>
         <ns10:Town>Johar</ns10:Town>
         <ns10:District>Lahore</ns10:District>
         <ns10:City>Lahore</ns10:City>
         <ns10:State>Punjab</ns10:State>
         <ns10:Country>Pakistan</ns10:Country>
         <ns10:Postal>54000</ns10:Postal>
      </ns10:CurrentAddress>
      <ns11:HomeAddress xmlns:ns11="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:AddressDetail">
         <ns11:AddressDetailId>195</ns11:AddressDetailId>
         <ns11:StreetNo>5</ns11:StreetNo>
         <ns11:HouseNo>123</ns11:HouseNo>
         <ns11:Town>Johar</ns11:Town>
         <ns11:District>Lahore</ns11:District>
         <ns11:City>Lahore</ns11:City>
         <ns11:State>Punjab</ns11:State>
         <ns11:Country>Pakistan</ns11:Country>
         <ns11:Postal>54000</ns11:Postal>
      </ns11:HomeAddress>
      <ns12:Height xmlns:ns12="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">6</ns12:Height>
      <ns13:Weight xmlns:ns13="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">100</ns13:Weight>
      <ns14:CNIC xmlns:ns14="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">35302</ns14:CNIC>
      <ns15:ContactInfo xmlns:ns15="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:ContactDetail">
         <ns15:HomePhone>454545</ns15:HomePhone>
         <ns15:CellPhone>3343434</ns15:CellPhone>
         <ns15:WorkPlacePhone>34343434</ns15:WorkPlacePhone>
         <ns15:Email>omer@gmail.com</ns15:Email>
      </ns15:ContactInfo>
      <ns16:MaritalStatus xmlns:ns16="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Single</ns16:MaritalStatus>
      <ns17:Nationality xmlns:ns17="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Pakistani</ns17:Nationality>
   </Person>
   <ResponseCode>PERSON MODULE SUCCESS - 00</ResponseCode>
   <ResponseMessage>Data Fetched Successfully</ResponseMessage>
</GetPersonResponse>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:m0="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01"

>

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="GetPersonResponse">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//m0:Religion"/>
</xsl:template>                     
<xsl:template match="//m0:Religion">
<xsl:value-of select="//m0:DateOfBirth"/>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT Mediator:**

```
<xslt key="gov:/repository/components/TestXSLT.xslt">

      <resource location="TestXSLT.xslt" key="gov:/repository/components/TestXSLT.xslt"></resource>
   </xslt>
```

**Error in WSO2 Testing Environment:**

```
<getBusRootResponse>
   <error>
      <errorCode>101508</errorCode>
      <errorMsgTitle>Connection Time Out</errorMsgTitle>
      <errorMsg>We are unable to get Connection to BusRoot Services</errorMsg>
   </error>
</getBusRootResponse>
```

**Error in WSO2 System Logs:**

```
ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='gov:/repository/components/TestXSLT.xslt'} against source XPath : s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[position()=1] reason : Unable to create an OMElement using XSLT result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT is not working fine, test it again in `http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php` : the result is not XML but flat text and the ESB can't handle such a result

This sample replace **Religion** node value with the value of **FatherName** node :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns6="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fo xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="ns6:Religion">
        <ns6:Religion><xsl:value-of select="../ns6:FatherName"/></ns6:Religion>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|*|comment()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```